# How to write cmake file when using singleton pattern in c++

Tags: c++, cmake, singleton

Now I'm going to transfer one of my project from VS project to cmake project. And in this project, I use a singleton class to manage all of the other modules. When in VS project, there is no problem, but in cmake project, there will have a circular dependency problem. For example, there is module "canbus" and the singleton class "manager".

In the canbus module, because it will use singleton class, so the CMakeLists.txt file is something like:

```
add_library(canbus STATIC
    CanBus.cpp)
target_include_directories(canbus PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(canbus PRIVATE
    manager)
```

And the manager class is like:

```
class Manager
{
public:
    static Manager* instance();
    canbus::CanBus* getCanBus();

private:
    canbus::CanBus _canBus;

private:
    Manager(void) {}
    ~Manager(void) {}
    Manager(const Manager& rhs) = delete;
    Manager& operator=(const Manager& rhs) = delete;
};
```

So the CMakeLists.txt file for the manager is like:

```
add_library(manager STATIC
    Manager.cpp)
target_include_directories(manager PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(manager PUBLIC
    canbus
    )
```

And there will have a circular dependency between canbus and manager, I'd like to know if there is a better way to handle this problem, or I should change the struct of my project? Hope someone familiar with cmake could give me some suggestions or advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If two static libraries depend on each other, it simply means that they should form a single library.

Another way is to not use `target_link_libraries` on library targets. They will compile fine, but you will have to call `target_link_libraries` with both libs when you try to use any in the executable target.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if not use `target_link_libraries`, which command should I use? because for the modern cmake, it is prefer to use `target_`. And yes, my project can compile and run, but I think because of the circular dependency, the compile speed is a little bit slow.